# Define >2 parameters & pass in values from one method to another

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

How do i actually pass in a value from a method to another method? I apologies for my lack in knowledge in c#. What i have done so far cannot work. I wish to pass the value 'MaxHeight' from Page() to 'MaxHeight' from fullNameControlLoaded().

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public Page(string _setArticles, string _setLength)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //testing!
    //send value to method 'fullNameControl_Loaded' (summary length of each ListBox item)
    int MaxHeight = 0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_setLength))
    {
        if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))
            MaxHeight = 30;
            fullNameControl_Loaded(null, null, MaxHeight);
    }      
}

private TextBlock m_textBlock;
void fullNameControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, int MaxHeight)
{
    m_textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    m_textBlock.MaxHeight = MaxHeight;   
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post what error you're getting/what actually happens, but let me guess, it's a `NullReferenceException` on the second-to-last line?

Comment: Please also consider improving the style. For example, `if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))` is a code hell for other developers who might be working on the code after you.

Comment: @oleksii: So sorry, actually the (_setLength.Contains("3")) is a parameter passed into the Silverlight control at Application_Startup(), so my issue is actually if i can do the same for Page() to fullNameControl_Loaded() :)

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Thank you! actually there was no NullReferenceException as the Silverlight control is not displayed at all. Setting the parameters to null will not work, so how may i do it instead, based on the sample i provided?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made it clear what's not working, but this:

```
if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))
    MaxHeight = 30;
    fullNameControl_Loaded(null, null, MaxHeight);
```

looks like it should probably be this:

```
if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))
{
    MaxHeight = 30;
    fullNameControl_Loaded(null, null, MaxHeight);
}
```

However, at that point `sender` will be null, so `fullNameControl_Loaded()` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

It seems unlikely that you *really* want to change the value of `m_textBlock` in the method... where were you expecting this to be initialized?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks! You see, is there any other way to pass the MaxHeight value of 30 of Page() to fullNameControl_Loaded(), how may i do so? Instead of defining the parameters @ Page()?

Comment: @mike868686: It's not clear *why* you want to call that method at that point, or what it's meant to do. Why are you assigning `m_textBlock` in that method? It might make more sense to have a method with *one* parameter which both `fullNameControl_Loaded()` and the `Page` constructor call.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: Thanks anyw! I really wish to change the value of m_textBlock, with an additional parameter passed in from Page(). The m_textBlock is a method defined @ a textblock in xaml, for i know setting its value will change its MaxHeight in my case. And so, how may i set its value from Page() & pass in that value to fullNameControl_Loaded()?

Comment: @mike868686: No, `m_textBlock` is a *variable*, not a method. I dare say you want to change the *properties* of the text block, but I don't think you want to really replace the value of the variable with a whole new `TextBlock`, do you?

Comment: Yes Sir, i do wish to change the values within fullNameControl_Loaded(), from what i define in Page(). How can i do so? Thanks & sorry.

Comment: @mike868686: So it *may* be enough just to remove the first line of your `fullNameControl_Loaded` method. But it depends whether anything else is actually populating `m_textBlock`.

Comment: @mike868686: And are you aware that your method no longer matches the normal event handler method signature? It looks like everything's become a bit confused, to be honest...

Comment: yes i understand. Thank you anyw. Did a workaround & now I'm facing another problem.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: Will you also kindly take a look @ this as well? Much appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883323/pass-2-parameters-silverlight-control-from-sharepoint-web-part-project-into-sil

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "MaxHeight" as a property in your class then Page constructor can set it's value and then when the fullNameControl_Loaded function runs, the value of the property will be the updated value from the page constructor.

private int maxHeight = 0;
public Page(string _setArticles, string _setLength)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        //testing!!!!
        //send value to method 'fullNameControl_Loaded'
        //(summary length of each ListBox item)
        maxHeight = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_setLength))
        {
            if (_setLength.Contains("_3"))
                maxHeight = 30;
                fullNameControl_Loaded(m_textBlock, null, MaxHeight);
        }      
    }

   private TextBlock m_textBlock;
    void fullNameControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, int MaxHeight)
    {
        m_textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        m_textBlock.MaxHeight = maxHeight;   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But do pardon me, will you show me the way? I do not get you.

Comment: So sorry, actually the (_setLength.Contains("3")) is a parameter passed into the Silverlight control at Application_Startup(), so my issue is actually if i can do the same for Page() to fullNameControl_Loaded() ?

Comment: @ Samir_Adel: Thanks anyw, i did a workaround for this. Now i face a more vexing issue, will you kindly take a look @ this & give me some pointers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883323/pass-2-parameters-silverlight-control-from-sharepoint-web-part-project-into-sil

Answer (score 0):

That's not a way how its done, declare your `MaxHeight` field in class scope then you can access to it from anywhere inside the class. don't modify generated event.